# Get transform context

Tags: reactjs, next.js, zooming

I have Nextjs app and I use react-zoom-pan-pinch for transformation one of containers.

```
<TransformWrapper
   limitToBounds={false}
   centerZoomedOut={true}
   minScale={0.5}
   maxScale={2}
   panning={{ excluded: ['input'] }}
   doubleClick={{disabled: true}}
 >
   {({zoomIn, zoomOut, setTransform, resetTransform, ...rest}) => {

    actionReset = resetTransform;
    increaseZoom = zoomIn;
    decreaseZoom = zoomOut;
    setScale = setTransform;

    const context = useTransformContext();
    console.log(context)

    return (
      <TransformComponent wrapperClass="project-global-canvas-area">
        ...
      </TransformComponent>
    );
  }}
</TransformWrapper>
```

I have 2 problems:

1. I need to have access to state of transform context, I use the useTransformContext hook, but I got the error:

Server Error
Error: Transform context mus be placed inside TransformWrapper

Where I can place this hook for getting the state?

2. I need state custom zoom value outside the transform component. There are no problem with zoomIn() and zoomOut(), but I have problem with setTransform().

I try call it:

`setScale(100, 100, 1.5)`

but nothing change with the error in console:

*Detected NaN set state values*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your second problem, but the first one happens because the children in `TransformWrapper` is a render prop. When you use hooks inside render props, they are being called from the parent component. In your case parent component is `TransformWrapper` and `useTransformContext` should be called from child **component**. Using render prop there `TransformWrapper` is the one that calls `useTransformContext`. You have to make new component that uses all that logic from render prop

```
 <TransformWrapper
   limitToBounds={false}
   centerZoomedOut={true}
   minScale={0.5}
   maxScale={2}
   panning={{ excluded: ['input'] }}
   doubleClick={{disabled: true}}
 >
   {(params) => <Comp {...params} />}
</TransformWrapper>

const Comp = ({zoomIn, zoomOut, setTransform, resetTransform, ...rest}) => {
  
    actionReset = resetTransform;
    increaseZoom = zoomIn;
    decreaseZoom = zoomOut;
    setScale = setTransform;

    const context = useTransformContext();   // here you will get the value
    console.log(context)

    return (
      <TransformComponent wrapperClass="project-global-canvas-area">
        ...
      </TransformComponent>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thnx! It works!